# How do you get type annotations from subclasses when inheriting?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a typed dictionary class, similar to `NamedTuple` but with the ability to subclass said tuples. Unfortunately, I find that in the base constructor where I want enforce types, I do not have access to the type annotations of subclasses.

Here's a minimal example:

```
class TypedDict:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    print(self.__annotations__)

    for k, v in kwargs.items():
      # Check if k is in self.__annotations__
      # Check that v has the same type as self.__annotations__[k]
      pass

class A(TypedDict):
  field_a: int = 3 

class B(A):
  field_b: int = 3
```

And on the console:

```
>>> a = A()
{'field_a': <class 'int'>}
>> b = B()
{'field_b': <class 'int'>}  # Where is 'field_a'?
```

How do I get the constructor in `TypedDict.__init__` to also see the annotations of `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), not `__annotations__`. `typing.get_type_hints` will merge the annotations of all classes in the MRO, as well as resolving string annotations.

```
type_hints = typing.get_type_hints(type(self))
```

Comment: What is the different between `get_type_hints(self)` and `get_type_hint(type(self))` as I see the first one returns type hints of just the first parent (in case class is inheriting multiple classes) and the later one shows all.

Comment: @AnkitJain: `get_type_hints` is only ever supposed to be called on a function, method, module, or class object. If you pass it something that isn't one of those types, the internal logic breaks. `get_type_hints(type(self))` passes a class object, while `get_type_hints(self)` passes an invalid argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have a workaround solution using the class `mro`.

```
class TypedDict:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    annotations = {}
    for cls in self.__class__.mro():
        # __annotations__ is only present when the class has defined annotations.
        annotations.update(getattr(cls, "__annotations__", {}))
    print(annotations)

    for k, v in kwargs.items():
      # Check if k is in self.__annotations__
      # Check that v has the same type as self.__annotations__[k]
      pass

class A(TypedDict):
  field_a: int = 3 

class B(A):
  field_b: int = 3
```

On the console:

```
>>> a = A()
{'field_a': <class 'int'>}
>> b = B()
{'field_a': <class 'int'>, 'field_b': <class 'int'>}
```